# How can I replace the default Glue42 toolbar with a custom application?

Tags: glue42

I found the application APIs, but there is no reference about instructing Glue Desktop to use a custom launcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the toolbar can be replaced with a custom one.

You need to:

1. Instruct Glue42 Desktop that your application should be considered as a shell and that it should be started automatically
2. Instruct Glue42 Desktop that it should use a custom launcher

Below are the entries for those.

Add the following to the root level of your application's config (to be placed under `%localAppData%\Tick42\GlueDesktop\config\apps\`):

```
{
    ...
    "shell": true,
    "autoStart": true,
    ...
}
```

And add the following to the `%localAppData%\Tick42\GlueDesktop\config\system.json` file:

```
{
    ...
    "useEmbeddedShell": false
    ...
}
```